# akka streams with spark streaming: messages are not delivered to actor; getting dead letters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to akka streaming. I am running the below example from github. But the messages to "Helloer" actor are not receiving and displaying in the output console.

**StreamingApp.scala**

```
import _root_.akka.actor.{ Actor, Props }
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.akka.{ ActorReceiver, AkkaUtils }

class Helloer extends ActorReceiver {
  override def preStart() = {
    println("")
    println("=== Helloer is starting up ===")
    println(s"=== path=${context.self.path} ===")
    println("")
  }
  def receive = {
    // store() method allows us to store the message so Spark Streaming knows about it
    // This is the integration point (from Akka's side) between Spark Streaming and Akka
    case s => store(s)
  }
}

object StreamingApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Configuration for a Spark application.
    // Used to set various Spark parameters as key-value pairs.
    val driverPort = 7777
    val driverHost = "localhost"
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]") // run locally with as many threads as CPUs
      .setAppName("Spark Streaming with Scala and Akka") // name in web UI
      .set("spark.logConf", "true")
      .set("spark.driver.port", driverPort.toString)
      .set("spark.driver.host", driverHost)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

    val actorName = "helloer"

    // This is the integration point (from Spark's side) between Spark Streaming and Akka system
    // It's expected that the actor we're now instantiating will `store` messages (to close the integration loop)
    val actorStream = AkkaUtils.createStream[String](ssc, Props[Helloer](), actorName)

    // describe the computation on the input stream as a series of higher-level transformations
    actorStream.reduce(_ + " " + _).print()

    // Custom receiver
    import pl.japila.spark.streaming.CustomReceiverInputDStream
    import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream
    val input: ReceiverInputDStream[String] = ssc.receiverStream[String](CustomReceiverInputDStream(StorageLevel.NONE))
    input.print()

    // Data Ingestion from Kafka
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

    // start the streaming context so the data can be processed
    // and the actor gets started
    ssc.start()

    // FIXME wish I knew a better way to handle the asynchrony
    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3)

    import _root_.akka.actor.ActorSystem
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("SparkStreamingAkka")

    val url = s"akka.tcp://sparkDriver@$driverHost:$driverPort/user/Supervisor0/$actorName"
    val helloer = actorSystem.actorSelection(url)
    helloer ! "Hello"
    helloer ! "from"
    helloer ! "Spark Streaming"
    helloer ! "with"
    helloer ! "Scala"
    helloer ! "and"
    helloer ! "Akka"

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout = MINUTES.toMillis(1))
    ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
  }
}
```

The program using a customeReceiverInputDstream implementation. The below is the customreceiver.

**customeReceiverInputDstream.scala**

```
package pl.japila.spark.streaming

import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

    case class CustomReceiverInputDStream[T](override val storageLevel: StorageLevel) extends Receiver[T](storageLevel) {
      def onStart() {
        println("\nHello from CustomReceiver.START\n")
      }

      def onStop() {
        println("\nHello from CustomReceiver.STOP\n")
      }
    }
```

The below is the output deadletter messages i am getting.

```
                  .
                  .
                  .

Hello from CustomReceiver.START

                  .
                  .
                  .

17/10/10 08:00:05 DEBUG RecurringTimer: Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1507636805400
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [6] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.475] [SparkStreamingAkka-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://SparkStreamingAkka/deadLetters] was not delivered. [7] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
17/10/10 08:00:05 DEBUG RecurringTimer: Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1507636805600
17/10/10 08:00:05 DEBUG RecurringTimer: Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1507636805600
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.693] [Executor task launch worker-0] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://streaming-actor-system-0@192.168.99.1:2552]
[INFO] [10/10/2017 08:00:05.696] [Executor task launch worker-0] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://streaming-actor-system-0@192.168.99.1:2552]
17/10/10 08:00:05 INFO ActorReceiverSupervisor: Supervision tree for receivers initialized at:akka://streaming-actor-system-0/user/Supervisor0
17/10/10 08:00:05 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver 0 onStart
17/10/10 08:00:05 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Waiting for receiver to be stopped
17/10/10 08:00:05 INFO ActorReceiverSupervisor: Started receiver worker at:akka://streaming-actor-system-0/user/Supervisor0/helloer

=== Helloer is starting up ===
=== path=akka://streaming-actor-system-0/user/Supervisor0/helloer ===

17/10/10 08:00:05 DEBUG RecurringTimer: Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1507636805800
17/10/10 08:00:05 DEBUG RecurringTimer: Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1507636805800
17/10/10 08:00:06 DEBUG RecurringTimer: Callback for BlockGenerator called at time 1507636806000
                                 . 
                                 .
                                 .
```

Comment: Why don´t you use "actorOf" instead of "actorSelection". According to the Akka doc: "actorSelection only ever looks up existing actors when messages are delivered, i.e. does not create actors, or verify existence of actors when the selection is created."

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 tried using actorOf. no dead letter messages this time. But didn't get the sent messages displayed as written in the above code.

Comment: there is not any println inside the case clause, what do you expect to be printed??

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 i am expecting the output mentioned in this link's description.https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-activator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see. The problem here is that the Actor that is created to act as Source, the "helloer" is started at a different ActorSystem and this code tries from find from the one named "SparkStreaminAkka" via akka.remote in another ActorSystem therefore a complete akka.tcp url is used. In this code it does not work, further investigation to be done... However it´s not mandatory to use a different ActorSystem in this example. A work around could be:

```
import _root_.akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.akka.{ActorReceiver, AkkaUtils}

class Helloer extends ActorReceiver {
  override def preStart() = {
    println("")
    println("=== Helloer is starting up ===")
    println(s"=== path=${context.self.path} ===")
    println("")
  }
  def receive = {
    // store() method allows us to store the message so Spark Streaming knows about it
    // This is the integration point (from Akka's side) between Spark Streaming and Akka
    case s => store(s)
  }
}


// Create a common actor system
object CreateActorSystem {
  lazy val as = _root_.akka.actor.ActorSystem("ActorSystemSpark")
}

object StreamingApp {
  import StreamingApp._

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Configuration for a Spark application.
    // Used to set various Spark parameters as key-value pairs.
    val driverPort = 7777
    val driverHost = "localhost"
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]") // run locally with as many threads as CPUs
      .setAppName("Spark Streaming with Scala and Akka") // name in web UI
      .set("spark.logConf", "true")
      .set("spark.driver.port", driverPort.toString)
      .set("spark.driver.host", driverHost)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))

    val actorName = "helloer"

    // This is the integration point (from Spark's side) between Spark Streaming and Akka system
    // It's expected that the actor we're now instantiating will `store` messages (to close the integration loop)

    // Pass actorsystem as parameter
    val actorStream = AkkaUtils.createStream[String](ssc, Props[Helloer](), actorName, actorSystemCreator = () => CreateActorSystem.as)

    // describe the computation on the input stream as a series of higher-level transformations
    actorStream.reduce(_ + " " + _).print()

    // Custom receiver
    import pl.japila.spark.streaming.CustomReceiverInputDStream
    import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
    import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream
    val input: ReceiverInputDStream[String] = ssc.receiverStream[String](CustomReceiverInputDStream(StorageLevel.NONE))
    input.print()

    // Data Ingestion from Kafka
    //import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

    // start the streaming context so the data can be processed
    // and the actor gets started
    ssc.start()

    // FIXME wish I knew a better way to handle the asynchrony
    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3)

    import _root_.akka.actor.ActorSystem

    val actorSystem = CreateActorSystem.as

    //Get the actor from the path. There is no nedd o akka.remote
    val helloer = actorSystem.actorSelection("/user/Supervisor0/helloer")

    helloer ! "Hello"
    helloer ! "from"
    helloer ! "Spark Streaming"
    helloer ! "with"
    helloer ! "Scala"
    helloer ! "and"
    helloer ! "Akka"

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout = MINUTES.toMillis(1))
    ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
  }
}
```

This will work

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your correction is working.I will get more knowledge on this to come up with akka.tcp

Comment: i am able to get the remote messaging worked by using `actorOf' . But still facing issue when used  `actorSelection`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724732/actorsystem-actorselection-is-not-working-for-remote-actors-where-actorof-is-wor